# Need Help with email setUp for my Ubuntu server

Tags: server, email

I need help setting up an admin email for my server. I have tried squirrelmail and roundcubemail but whenever I get to the stage of typing my login details in, nothing works. Login just keeps failing.
I honestly dont even mind using a gmail account or something like that, I just want to be able to read incoming messages from my website's "Contact" page.

Comment: If you're not familiar with mail servers, I strongly recommend using accounts from third-parties (for example Gmail, as you wrote). Mail servers can be hard to administrate, even for experienced people.

Answer (score 0):

actually there is a huge guide which i can not write here to build a mail server in your Ubuntu system , please visit that. That will guide in  Postfix 2.7 (SMTP Server/MTA) & Dovecot 1.2 (Pop3/IMAP Server).

http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Mail_Server_setup

Comment: you are welcome and let us know any difficulty,:)